# Matching list element with dataframe element python

Tags: python, regex, pandas, list, dataframe

I have some lists like follows:

```
l1 = ['Category=worker,manager','Name=Ana,Tom', 'Task=Cleaning,Plumbing']
```

And then I have dataframe df:

```
Name    | Category        | Task       | OrderNum

Bryan   | worker,manager  | Cleaning,Plumbing | 2
Ana,Tom | worker,manager  | Cleaning,Plumbing | 3
```

I want to find that for a list item, find the matching value in the respective df's column, & when all matches are found for a list, then return its value from the `OrderNum` column.

How can I get that?

Comment: This list is impossible. Please post data strutures that don't throw syntax errors.

Comment: @timgeb Corrected the list

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given:

```
>>> l1 = ['Category=worker,manager','Name=Ana,Tom', 'Task=Cleaning,Plumbing']
>>> 
>>> df
      Name        Category               Task  OrderNum
0    Bryan  worker,manager  Cleaning,Plumbing         2
1  Ana,Tom  worker,manager  Cleaning,Plumbing         3
```

you can form a query from `l1` like this:

```
>>> query = ' and '.join("{} == '{}'".format(*s.split('=')) for s in l1)
>>> query
"Category == 'worker,manager' and Name == 'Ana,Tom' and Task == 'Cleaning,Plumbing'"
```

... and then issue

```
>>> df.query(query)
      Name        Category               Task  OrderNum
1  Ana,Tom  worker,manager  Cleaning,Plumbing         3
```

or

```
>>> df.query(query)['OrderNum']
1    3
Name: OrderNum, dtype: int64
```

or

```
>>> result, = df.query(query)['OrderNum']
>>> result
3
```

if you expect exactly one hit, or

```
>>> result = df.query(query)['OrderNum'].iat[0]
>>> result
3
```

if you expect at least one hit and want to assign `result` to the first hit, regardless of how many there are.

Comment: or `result, *_ = df.query(query)['OrderNum']` if there are more than 1.

Comment: @coldspeed maybe `iat[0]` is better in this case because no need to unpack a potentially large series.

Comment: @timgeb It's giving me empty dataframe in result. But the df is definitely not empty.

Comment: @user10096621 then your dataframe does not look like you say it does. As you can see I literally copy-pasted an interpreter session. (That's what you get for not posting a [MCVE] I guess :) ).

Comment: @timgeb query gives "Category == 'worker,manager' and Name == 'Ana,Tom' and Task == 'Cleaning,Plumbing'", however df is Name        Category               Task  OrderNum
0    Bryan  worker,manager  Cleaning,Plumbing         2
1  Ana,Tom  worker,manager  Cleaning,Plumbing         3
Does the order of the columns matter?

Comment: @user10096621 I can't help you without a [MCVE] in the question.